# Specific working example needed using IProgress interface described by Albahari

Tags: wpf, parallel-processing, async-await, progress, c#-5.0

I am a neophyte at C# threading. I am trying to get my head around how to make 100K web requests, *with some degree of parallelism*, and report progress real-time to the GUI:

```
urls processed so far: ######
total moved so far:    ######
timed out so far:      ####3
```

I am reading pages 596ff in *C# 5.0 in a Nutshell* by the Albahari brothers, the section on Progress Reporting.  At this point, I don't see how in the Progress instance these counters would be incremented in a thread-safe manner, and exactly how/where the UI gets updated. EVen in the example specifically discussing the differences between writing to the console and writing to the GUI, the book uses `Console.WriteLine`. I'd be grateful for an example showing exactly what occurs in the Progress instance -- incrementing some int variables and writing to a textbox, for example.

Comment: Your GUI has a `SynchronizationContext` where you can post your UI update. Can you post where what code you already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a [walkthrough on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html), in particular pointing out the caveats:

- `IProgress<T>.Report` is asynchronous, so it works best if the object you send it is immutable.
- By convention, the `IProgress<T> progress` passed into your TAP method may be `null`, so check for that before reporting progress.
- `Progress<T>` works best with a UI or other single-threaded `SynchronizationContext`.
- Exceptions raised from `Progress<T>`'s handler go directly to the `SynchronizationContext`, so avoid throwing exceptions from the progress report handler.

There's also a [blog post here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx) and the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) are quite good.