# Async method with custom status

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Suppose I have a class Job which has a long running method void Execute() which is executed in another thread (i.e. Task.Run(()=>job.Execute()).

In the UI, I need to show the user a status of the running job in realtime with some labels and percents, i.e. "Authenticating" / "Waiting for connection" / "Retrieving data xx%" / "Parsing data xx%" etc.

What would you recommend to do to implement this correctly? Should I declare a GetStatus() method in the Job class, poll it with a timer in the UI, update it within the Execute() method, and be aware of Race conditions with some lock? It seems a bit "rough"... Something more elegant?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of application is it? WPF?

Comment: No it is a Windows Form application

Comment: Also, check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036912/specific-working-example-needed-using-iprogress-interface-described-by-albahari).

Comment: Also [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: Have you searched about background task? I think it can help you. While your task is executing in background in other thread, you can update UI in main thread. In addition you can set custom status message using `backgroundTask.Result` property.